# Why does installation of R package fftwtools fail after successful installation of FFTW 3.3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: r

My goal is to install R package "fftwtools" on my computer equipped with Ubuntu 20.04 as the only OS.  After reading previous postings on stackoverflow, I installed the latest version of fftw (3.3.10), including the development version using

```
sudo apt-get install fftw3-dev
```

I can see the library files in /usr/local/lib as follows:

```
dorazio@toucan:/usr/local/lib$ ls -la
total 3640
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096 Feb 27 10:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Apr 27  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Feb 27 10:52 cmake
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3581658 Feb 27 10:52 libfftw3.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      888 Feb 27 10:52 libfftw3.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    46990 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_omp.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      936 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_omp.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    52098 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_threads.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      948 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_threads.la
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Feb 27 10:52 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x  4 root staff    4096 Mar 13  2021 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff    4096 Aug  3  2020 python3.8
drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff    4096 May 26  2018 R
```

However, I get the following error message when attempting to install R package fftwtools:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> 
> install.packages('fftwtools')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/fftwtools_0.9-11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 174321 bytes (170 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 170 KB

* installing *source* package ‘fftwtools’ ...
** package ‘fftwtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for pkg-config... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars

fftwtools 0.9-10
================

compiler flags: -I/usr/local/include 
link argument:  -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 

** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include        -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i2PIHO/r-base-4.1.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fftwtools.c -o fftwtools.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include        -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i2PIHO/r-base-4.1.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fftwtools_init.c -o fftwtools_init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o fftwtools.so fftwtools.o fftwtools_init.o -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(assert.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: fftwtools.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fftwtools’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fftwtools’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp4FsjOe/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("fftwtools") :
  installation of package ‘fftwtools’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

In response to Karim's suggestion, I built the fftw from tarball fftw-3.3.10.tar.gz as follows:

```
./configure --enable-threads --enable-openmp --enable-avx
make
make install
```

This created several libfftw3*.* files in /usr/local/lib :

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096 Feb 27 10:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Apr 27  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Feb 27 10:52 cmake
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3581658 Feb 27 10:52 libfftw3.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      888 Feb 27 10:52 libfftw3.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    46990 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_omp.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      936 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_omp.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    52098 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_threads.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      948 Feb 27 10:53 libfftw3_threads.la
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Feb 27 10:52 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x  4 root staff    4096 Mar 13  2021 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff    4096 Aug  3  2020 python3.8
drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff    4096 May 26  2018 R
```

Then I attempted to install fftwtools from CRAN, but this produced the same error messaged that prompted my original posting.

Comment: Perhaps try the "alternative manual build instructions" here: https://github.com/krahim/fftwtools#fftwtools

Comment: @Robert when you install ` fftw3-dev` the files end up below `/usr`, and what you show as a manual listing `/usr/local/` is *not* the same but a different, possibly conflicting build. I would remove the files in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c2d4u ("CRAN-to-Deb(ian)-For-Ubuntu") repo has a binary for you.  How to set this up is described at the [README for Ubuntu at CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#get-5000-cran-packages).

I maintain a particular Rocker container variant that wires R's own `install.packages` up to use those binaries where available (which relies on the [bspm](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=bspm) package), and it just turned by `install.packages("fftwtools")` request into the installation of the binary `r-cran-fftwtools_0.9-11-1cran1.2004.0_amd64.deb` (for Ubuntu 20.04) -- and that takes care of all dependencies.

You can replicate this (using Docker) via the two or three commands

```
docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-bspm:20.04 bash
```

to launch the container, and start a `bash` shell. I then update the indices and ask for the installation:

```
apt update -qq
Rscript -e 'install.packages("fftwtools")'
```

and that takes care of everything. Full log:

```
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-bspm:20.04 bash
root@14a6fb8a9329:/# apt update -qq
31 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@14a6fb8a9329:/# Rscript -e 'install.packages("fftwtools")'
Loading required package: utils
Tracing function "install.packages" in package "utils"
Install system packages as root...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/edd/r-4.0/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter4.0/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libfftw3-double3 amd64 3.3.8-2ubuntu1 [728 kB]                                                                                                            
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal/main amd64 r-cran-fftwtools amd64 0.9-11-1cran1.2004.0 [167 kB]                                                                                  
Fetched 895 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                      
Selecting previously unselected package libfftw3-double3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 20688 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfftw3-double3_3.3.8-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfftw3-double3:amd64 (3.3.8-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-fftwtools.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-fftwtools_0.9-11-1cran1.2004.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-fftwtools (0.9-11-1cran1.2004.0) ...
Setting up libfftw3-double3:amd64 (3.3.8-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up r-cran-fftwtools (0.9-11-1cran1.2004.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
root@14a6fb8a9329:/#
```

Now, *none of this relied on Docker* and I used it just as a demo. If you wire up the 'c2d4u.team' repo as described on the README.md linked to above you can then do the standard `sudo apt install r-cran-fftwtool`.  If you want, you can also look into `bspm` to make this accessible from R via `install.packages()` but that is really just an extra.

Come ask on the r-sig-debian list with any specific questions.

Comment: Dirk's proposal completely solved my problem!  I deleted the previous build of fftw3-dev from /usr/local/lib as Dirk had recommended; then I added the c2d4u.team repository and installed the fftwtools package directly as follows:  ``` sudo apt install r-cran-fftwtools ```  Many thanks Dirk!!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Robert. These binaries are very convenient and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across this problem before, but the build file has been updated in attempt to accomodate multiple systems.

Can you try building fftw from the tarball?

So remove the ubuntu packages, then install fftw from the tarball, and let me know if you get the same error.

http://www.fftw.org/download.html

Best wishes,

Comment: I built the fftw from tarball fftw-3.3.10.tar.gz, which created the same library files given in my original post.  Then I got the same error when attempting to install fftwtools from CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I did not want to upgrade to R 4 just yet. However, installing this library `libfftw3-dev` using the command  `sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev` solved the issue.